# Bug: adding entity to n:n relation does not change CodeFluentEntityState

Tags: codefluent

I have two entities with a n:n relationship. Let's say 'persons and addresses'.
If I add an address to person.addresses the CodeFluentEntityState of person is not changed.
In the baseSave of person is a function SaveAddressesRelations which would normally save the added addresses. However, because the CodeFluentEntityState of person is not changed this code won't be reached and the address is not saved.

Please fix it, the bug causes big problems in my application..

I have made a small project to clarify:

```
<cf:project defaultNamespace="test" xmlns:cf="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/2005/1" xmlns:cfx="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/modeler/2008/1" xmlns:cfom="http://www.softfluent.com/codefluent/producers.model/2005/1" createDefaultMethodForms="true" createDefaultApplication="false" createDefaultHints="false">
  <cf:import path="Default.Surface.cfp" />
  <cf:entity name="Person" namespace="GreatPersons" categoryPath="/test">
    <cf:property name="Guid" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="Name" />
    <cf:property name="Addresses" typeName="GreatPersons.AddressCollection" relationPropertyName="Persons" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:entity name="Address" namespace="GreatPersons" categoryPath="/test">
    <cf:property name="Guid" key="true" />
    <cf:property name="Street" />
    <cf:property name="Persons" typeName="GreatPersons.PersonCollection" relationPropertyName="Addresses" />
  </cf:entity>
  <cf:producer name="Business Object Model (BOM)" typeName="CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom.CodeDomProducer, CodeFluent.Producers.CodeDom">
    <cf:configuration compileWithVisualStudio="true" compile="false" codeDomProviderTypeName="CSharp" targetDirectory="..\Test\CodefluentCode" cfx:targetProjectLayout="Update" cfx:targetProject="..\Test\Test.csproj" />
  </cf:producer>
</cf:project>
```

The followind code won't save the relation between the person and the address:

```
var newPerson = new Person
{
    Name = "Napoleon"
};
newPerson.Save();

var newAddress = new Address
{
    Street = "Saint Helena Road"
};
newAddress.Save();

newPerson.Addresses.Add(newAddress);
newPerson.Save();
```

The save method of the person generated by the BOM producer looks like this:

```
protected virtual bool BaseSave(bool force)
{
    if ((this.EntityState == CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityState.ToBeDeleted))
    {
        this.Delete();
        return false;
    }
    CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityActionEventArgs evt = new CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityActionEventArgs(this, CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityAction.Saving, true);
    this.OnEntityAction(evt);
    if ((evt.Cancel == true))
    {
        return false;
    }
    CodeFluentPersistence.ThrowIfDeleted(this);
    this.Validate();
    if (((force == false) 
                && (this.EntityState == CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityState.Unchanged)))
    {
        return false;
    }
    CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentPersistence persistence = CodeFluentContext.Get(test.Constants.testStoreName).Persistence;
    persistence.CreateStoredProcedureCommand(null, "Person", "Save");
    persistence.AddParameter("@Person_Guid", this.Guid, CodeFluentPersistence.DefaultGuidValue);
    persistence.AddParameter("@Person_Name", this.Name, default(string));
    persistence.AddParameter("@_trackLastWriteUser", persistence.Context.User.Name);
    persistence.AddParameter("@_rowVersion", this.RowVersion);
    System.Data.IDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        reader = persistence.ExecuteReader();
        if ((reader.Read() == true))
        {
            this.ReadRecordOnSave(reader);
        }
        CodeFluentPersistence.NextResults(reader);
    }
    finally
    {
        if ((reader != null))
        {
            reader.Dispose();
        }
        persistence.CompleteCommand();
    }
    this.SaveAddressesRelations();
    this.OnEntityAction(new CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityActionEventArgs(this, CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityAction.Saved, false, false));
    this.EntityState = CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityState.Unchanged;
    return true;
}
```

It is the *SaveAddressesRelations* that normally will save the relation between a person and an address. However, there is a line almost at the top that will prevent the save:

```
if (((force == false) 
            && (this.EntityState == CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentEntityState.Unchanged)))
{
    return false;
}
```

If the CodeFluentEntityState of the person is unchanged. The relation between person and address won't be saved.

The following code would have saved the relation:

```
var newAddress = new Address
{
    Street = "Saint Helena Road"
};
newAddress.Save();

var newPerson = new Person
{
    Name = "Napoleon"
};
newPerson.Addresses.Add(newAddress);
newPerson.Save();
```

In my opinion the SaveAddressesRelations should be placed before the CodeFluentEntityState check OR adding an address should toggle the CodeFluentEntityState to Changed.

Comment: CodeFluent Entities does not guarantee any consistency between entities that were loaded in the memory at some point in time. There is no notion of "context" as you seem to expect, so it does not look like a bug, but please provide some reproducing code to make sure.

Comment: Simon, this is an odd answer. The bom-producer produces a function itself to save the relation. If i would have changed some property of person, it would have saved the relation fine. But only when I don't change anything about the person except for an address the relation between address and person is not saved. I can't imagine the purpose of Codefluent is to save the relation 'sometimes'... I'll make a small project te clarify.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both code do save the relation with the model you provided. PS: I've never used the word "sometimes".

Comment: Hi Simon, It turns out I was breaking the mechanism myself. I was changing private properties because of caching purposes and thus preventing triggers. MEA MAXIMA CULPA!